# Trying to do some normalization and keep getting error

Tags: c++, int

I keep getting the error "error: invalid conversion from ‘int*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive] " and I do not know why;

I am doing this for homework and we have yet to discuss pointers so using them is out of the question.

here is my code (PS I am new to programming)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>


using namespace std;

double normalize (int , int);
double normalize (double,double);
int n=0;
int i=0;
const  double SIZE=5;
double mean=0;
double meanDivide;



int main()
{
    char dataType;
    int norm[5];
    int value =1;


    cout<<"Which data type do you want (i, d): ";
    cin>>dataType;

    if (dataType =='i')
    {
        while(value<5) 
        {
            cout<<"Enter value "<<value << ": ";
            cin>> norm[n];
            value++;

        }
    }
    else if (dataType=='d')
    {
        cout<<"Enter value "<<value << ": ";
            cin>> norm[n];
            value++;

    }


    cout<<"The mean is: "<<normalize(norm,5)/* The error comes from here and 

I do not know what to do or why */
<<endl;

    cout<<"The normalized values: "<<endl;

    int j=0;

    cout<<"norm[1] = "<<norm[j]<<endl;
    j++;
    cout<<"norm[2] = "<<norm[j]<<endl;
    j++;
    cout<<"norm[3] = "<<norm[j]<<endl;
    j++;
    cout<<"norm[4] = "<<norm[j]<<endl;
    j++;
    cout<<"norm[5] = "<<norm[j]<<endl;





    return 0;

}


double normalize(int norm[],int SIZE)
{


    while(i<6)
    {
        meanDivide +=norm[i];
        i++;
    }
    i=0;

    while (i<n)
    {

        norm[i] -=meanDivide;
        i++;
    }

    mean = meanDivide / 5;

    return mean;
}

double normalize (double norm[],double SIZE)
{


    while(i<6)
    {
        meanDivide +=norm[i];
        i++;
    }
    i=0;

    while (i<n)
    {

        norm[i] -=meanDivide;
        i++;
    }
    mean = meanDivide / 5;

    return mean;
}
```

This is the output I should be getting.

```
//For integers:

Which data type do you want (i, d): i
Enter value 1: 0
Enter value 2: 3
Enter value 3: 4
Enter value 4: 8
Enter value 5: 12
The mean is: 5.4
The normalized values:
norm[1] = -5
norm[2] = -2
norm[3] = -1
norm[4] = 2
norm[5] = 6


//For doubles:
Which data type do you want (i, d): d
Enter value 1: 5.5
Enter value 2: 1.23
Enter value 3: 2.02
Enter value 4: 9.99
Enter value 5: 6.32
The mean is: 5.012
The normalized values:
norm[1] = 0.488
norm[2] = -3.782
norm[3] = -2.992
norm[4] = 4.978
norm[5] = 1.308
```

Comment: You are declaring your methods like `double normalize (int , int);` but implementing them like `normalize(int [], int)`.

Comment: Try to avoid using global variables, using them is a bad practice. And there's one thing I'm not understanding... weren't you supposed to increment `n` each time you receive a value?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux what should I do to fix it ?

Comment: @JeffersonCarvalho yeah I forgot that part ,  Initially it was in there but e I tried removing and readding to see if my errors would go away .

Comment: Also, it seems you are using the variable `meanDivide` without initializing it, which can cause undefined behavior.

Comment: @JeffersonCarvalho okay I will Initialize it , but my main problem is just the invalid conversion from ‘int*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive] "error

Comment: Well, probably It's just what @FrançoisAndrieux pointed. Change the declaration you put in the beginning of the code to match with what the actual function is(`double normalize (int , int);` to `double normalize (int[] , int);`). This should do the trick

Comment: Step 1: narrow down the problem into a [MCVE].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring your methods like this :

```
double normalize (int , int);
double normalize(double*, double);
```

Yet you are trying to implement them like :

```
double normalize(int norm[], int SIZE) {/*...*/}
double normalize(double norm[], double SIZE) {/*...*/}
```

Notice that the argument types are not the same, `int, int` is not the same as `int[], int`. This means that your implementation is actually defining a whole new function, unrelated to the ones you declared at the top of your example. When you call your `normalize` function, only the initial declaration is found, and it tries to match `int norm[5]` to `int` which it fails. To fix this, make sure the declaration is correct. Change the declarations to this :

```
double normalize(int[], int);
double normalize(double[], double);
```

This will fix the error you are asking about in this question, but your example still has other problems. Some of them are identified in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You declare prototypes for non-pointer parameters:

```
double normalize (int , int);
double normalize (double,double);
```

You call with pointer arguments:

```
cout<<"The mean is: "<<normalize(norm,5)
```

The C++ compiler at that point does not care about the implementation with pointer arguments below. Try matching implementation to prototypes.

Also
a) you increment `value` but use `n` as index:
            cin>> norm[n];
            value++;

b) you ignore SIZE
c) SIZE should be unsigned int in both cases
d) your example is not minimal (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

You might find this generally useful:
https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/